# How to cover lines in mapDispatchToProps with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

> My question is how do we cover these lines in jest?

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        submitClaimsForm: form => {
            dispatch(submitClaimsForm(form));
        }
    };
};
```

---

In my component this is what the redux connected area looks like:

```
export function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        formNonMember: state.form,
        submissionSuccess: state.claimSubmission.submissionSuccess
    };
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        submitClaimsForm: form => {
            dispatch(submitClaimsForm(form));
        }
    };
};

let AdditionalDetailsFormConnect = reduxForm({
    form: 'AdditionalDetails',
    destroyOnUnmount: false
})(AdditionalDetailsForm);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(AdditionalDetailsFormConnect);
```

And this is how the dispatched action is used:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.props.submitClaimsForm(this.props.formattedForm);
}
```

Next this is what the actual action looks like:

```
import {postClaimsForm} from '../shared/services/api';

export const Actions = {
    SET_SUBMISSION_STATUS: 'SET_SUBMISSION_STATUS'
};

export const submitClaimsForm = form => dispatch => {
    return postClaimsForm(form)
        .then(res => {
            // console.log('promise returned:', res);
            return dispatch({
                type: Actions.SET_SUBMISSION_STATUS,
                submissionSuccess: true
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // console.log('error returned:', error);
            return dispatch({
                type: Actions.SET_SUBMISSION_STATUS,
                submissionSuccess: false
            });
        });
};
```

**What I've tried so far:**

```
it('mapDispatchToProps works as expected', () => {
    const actionProps = mapDispatchToProps({
        submitClaimsForm: jest.fn()
    });
    actionProps.submitClaimsForm();
    expect(submitClaimsForm).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But this errors and tells me that `dispatch` is undefined.

I also have this test, which passes, it tells me that `submitClaimsForm` has been called, but it just covers the lines for `onSubmit`:

```
it('onSubmit is called on submit', function() {
    const spyOnSubmit = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onSubmit');
    const mockHandleSubmit = jest.fn(wrapper.instance().onSubmit);
    const submitClaimsForm = jest.fn(wrapper.instance().submitClaimsForm);

    wrapper.setProps({
        handleSubmit: mockHandleSubmit,
        submitClaimsForm
    });

    wrapper.find('MyForm').simulate('submit');

    expect(mockHandleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spyOnSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(submitClaimsForm).toHaveBeenCalled();  // <--
});
```

Comment: Hmm what's the real purpose of the test you are trying to write? Testing `mapDispatchToProps` *kind of* feels like you're testing `react-redux`. The second test looks more appropriate IMO, albeit more of an integration test.

Comment: @James Oh yeah we have the Actions file already fully covered... that function `submitClaimsForm` has been tested, but it's just line coverage that jest is complaining about :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `mapDispatchToProps works as expected` test fails is because `mapDispatchToProps` expects a `dispatch` function to be passed in, not the map itself (that's what `mapDispatchToProps` *returns*).

This should work:

```
jest.mock('./actions');
import * as actions from './actions';

it('mapDispatchToProps calls the appropriate action', async () => {
  // mock the 'dispatch' object
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  const actionProps = mapDispatchToProps(dispatch);
  const formData = { ... };
  actionProps.submitClaimsForm(formData);
  // verify the appropriate action was called
  expect(actions.submitClaimsForm).toHaveBeenCalled(formData);
});
```